# Not able to format resulting number into decimal form

Tags: jquery, numbers

Why would this not show #total as a decimal? 
 The value of the inputs in class="total" are a function result that stores the value in 2 decimal format.  The function to display the row totals works fine but when I use the below code to total the rows when the qty field changes, the mat is correct and the change takes place correctly, but it in an int style not a currency format (2 decimal places).  I have tried toPrecision as well with no change.

```
$('[name^=qty]').change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('input.total').each(function() {
        sum += $(this).val();
    });

    $('#total').val(sum).toFixed(2);
    });
```

Here is the code that totals each row

```
function Tot(x,price,y) {
var total = CurrencyFormatted(x*price);
var v = document.getElementById(y);
v.setAttribute('value',total);}
```

All of these functions run just fine, totaling correctly and updating as expected, with exception to the decimal places in the grand total field.

Below is the html that I am using for each row and then the total

```
<td>$<input id="t1" disabled="disabled" size="8" value="0.00" class="total" />
...
<input disabled="disabled" id="total" name="total" size="8" value="0.00" />
```

There is nothing in the css that would change the format of the number either in the class or the table structure.  I am at a complete loss, but hopefully someone will see something I don't.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input.total').each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat( $(this).val() );
});

$('#total').val( sum.toFixed(2) );
```

EDIT, since i was busy i didn't explain my answer, Greg Pettit did, so here's the explanation

You were trying to chain toFixed() to something that's not a number. Also, you weren't converting your retrieved values to floats. JS may have handled the latter, but better to run it through parseFloat as per sample

Comment: You were trying to chain toFixed() to something that's not a number. Also, you weren't converting your retrieved values to floats. JS may have handled the latter, but better to run it through parseFloat as per sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parseFloat function to do it:

```
parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
```

for more examples:

[JQuery Type examples](http://docs.jquery.com/Types)

Answer (score 0):

`val` returns a `String` object, not a number. you'll need to call `parseFloat` or cast to `Number` before calling `toFixed(2)`